# Adjust (column size of) all visible dataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm trying to create a generic JS method that will adjust (`fnAdjustColumnSizing()`) all visible dataTables. Problem is that I just can't get the syntax quite right...

So far, i got this close:

```
$.fn.dataTable.fnTables(true); //this gets all visible dataTables...
$('#givenTable').dataTable().fnAdjustColumnSizing(); //this  adjusts a given dataTable

$.each($.fn.dataTable.fnTables(true), function(singleTable) {
    $(singleTable).dataTable().fnAdjustColumnSizing();
});  // And this just don't work! Don't know why...
```

Any ideas or suggestions on an alternative way to acomplish this?

**EDIT**: I marked the answer below as the correct answer but i did found what was wrong on my original approach (and will include it as it may be usefull to others): It is the syntax of the `$.each`'s provided function, which should receive 2 parameters, being the first one the index and the second the element itself. So:

```
$.each($.fn.dataTable.fnTables(true), function(idx, singleTable) {
    $(singleTable).dataTable().fnAdjustColumnSizing();
});  // This works!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DataTables API documentation contains [an example](http://datatables.net/api#fnTables) that might help you:

```js
var table = $.fn.dataTable.fnTables(true);
if ( table.length > 0 ) {
    $(table).dataTable().fnAdjustColumnSizing();
}
```

Comment: Yey, it's a different approach (selecting all "tables" tags) but it surely works. Anyway, I discovered what was wrong on my first approach and will be editing to include that too. Thanks.